# Output a custom shortcode for a specific product category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, shortcode

I am trying to add an extra button to my products on my shop page but only to a specific category. I have gotten this far but I cannot seem to call it up right.

```
if (!function_exists('add_accessory_button')){
function add_accessory_button() {
  global $product;
  $product_cat = $product->product_cat;

  if( has_term( 'dealqualify',$product_cat ) && in_the_loop() ) {
    $link = get_post_meta( $product->ID, ‘acc_link’, true );
    echo do_shortcode('<br>[button link="' . esc_attr($link) . '"]View Accessory[/button]');
} }
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','add_accessory_button');
}
```

Any help to pinpoint my mistake would be appreciated.

Comment: Just updated the shortcode line code (it seems better this way) … but if it's working for you don't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of errors in your code

You need to set **`has_term()`** this way in your condition to make it work:

```
has_term( 'dealqualify', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() )
```

Also for the product ID do it this way: **`$product->get_id()`**... I have try to correct the others errors too...

So your code should be something like:

```
if ( ! function_exists('add_accessory_button')){

    function add_accessory_button() {
        global $product;
        if( has_term( 'dealqualify', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && in_the_loop() ) {
            $link = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'acc_link', true );
            echo '<br>' . do_shortcode("[button link='$link']View Accessory[/button]");
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','add_accessory_button');
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This should work now…